# How to report a bug associated with a certain user's profile while respecting user's privacy?

Tags: support, bug, privacy

I found a display bug. I am only able to see it on a certain user's profile. I think it would be rather rude to drop a link to this person's profile in a Meta question. How can I report this bug?

Comment: Just to play Devil's Advocate - what would be rude about displaying a user's profile that they've already acknowledged is public and for the world to see?  Unless the profile contained something *inappropriate*, which would merit a completely different report path anyway...

Comment: @Makoto Because it violates reasonable assumptions one might have about how it is likely to be viewed in practice.

Comment: @JETM:  A reasonable assumption is that it will be viewed.  I'm not sure if the need for reservation is warranted since it will be the case that someone will find their profile *eventually*...

Comment: @JETM: User's profiles are *public*. Any "assumptions one might have about how it is likely to be viewed" are of dubious merit. If you don't want something viewed by the public, you don't *put it in public*.

Comment: @ModusTollens We don't accept bug reports via that support channel unless they prevent someone from logging in to post on Meta in the first place.

Comment: Only thing I would want to protect the user from by not disclosing their profile is the meta effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a bug in one of the editable sections of the profile you should see if you can figure out what causes it and reproduce it either in your own profile or in the profile of a sock puppet that you created for this. This has several benefits:

- You won't have to worry about the user editing their profile to remove the buggy behavior.
- You might gain a better understanding of what causes the bug and what doesn't.
- Avoids any potential meta effect on an unsuspecting person.

If the bug involves something like a specific question title or something similar you could try to reproduce it temporarily in MSE's [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/323179).

Lastly, you always have the option of trying to find other people who have the same bug in their profile. The most powerful tool to use for this is [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

---

If it's not that type of bug you will probably have to bite the bullet: post a question where you show the behavior in a screenshot so that people don't have to go to the profile and include a discreet link to the profile.

In the end, people shouldn't have stuff they don't want seen in a public profile.